# Using hidden variables in recursive loops

Tags: python

I am using a recursive loop to build a json object one record at at time. Is it appropriate to use an underscore to denote a hidden variable here - so that record can be recycled/anonymous in the name space?

```
output = []

for x in y:
    _record = {'title': x.name}
    _record['attribute z'] = x.some_attribute
    output.append(_record)
```

Comment: The leading underscore is just a naming convention, it doesn't change how the interpreter treats the variable.

Comment: A local variable is already "hidden", because nothing from another scope can access it.  Giving it an underscore prefix to denote it as private (as is done sometimes for attributes) is therefore unnecessary and not standard convention.  If you want to avoid giving this variable a name at all, simplify your code so a variable is unnecessary: `output = [{'title': x.name, 'attribute z': x.some_attribute} for x in y]`

Comment: Leading underscores are mainly used for object attributes. It's a hint that the attribute should be considered "private".

Comment: Your code never recurses...

Comment: I think most python coders would see that "_record" is being appended to the output list and is not supposed to be used after the for loop. That being said, I'm a little unsure about @Samwise's comment regarding scope, the way your code is written someone could use the last result of "_record" outside the for loop -- it would be bad practice instead of just accessing the end of "output" but it is not illegal.

Comment: Please clarify if this is within a function scope, I currently think that this is an imperative-style code which executes in some script or notebook ? But, without the context it's hard to answer. Also, as @MathiasR.Jessen said, this code never recurses, that's why I'm asking.